# R how to get amount of memory available to R on Linux

Tags: r, linux

I know, that I can query `/proc/meminfo` with the following:

```
memfree <- tryCatch(
    as.numeric(system("/usr/bin/awk '/MemAvailable/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo", intern=TRUE))*1024,
    error = function(e) 0)
```

Unfortunately it has 2 major limitations:

- Spawning the subshell has heavy memory footprint in itself, and I've seen it many times to fail while still there were many MB of memory available.
- It is not compatible with per-process memory constraints [assigned by kernel API](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrlimit).

Surely R must have a means to know the actual size of the memory available to it. But where to find it?

---

I've put a bug on R's bugtracker: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16793

Comment: On Linux, R will grab all the memory it can.

Comment: @HongOoi Does it mean, that R on Linux is essentially unaware of the memory limits?

Comment: Not sure whether I really understand your questions as I am not an expert on the matters that you describe, but I monitor the free memory independently from R via `sar -r 1` and then pipe the output to a file. The `sar -r 1` command gets executed periodically (every second) by a bash script. I don't do the reading of the output file with R and the whole thing lags a little bit, but maybe something along the lines of this can help you out...

Comment: @cryo111 This technique will certainly get around the first problem. But it doesn't solve the problem when R process has memory cap on it (which I believe is a good practice on Linux)

Comment: Just looked at your bug report. Funny - the whole reason why I did this monitoring is exactly the same as yours. The package that you mention in the bug report is very interesting and could also potentially help me. But I think what you are asking for in this bug report goes at the very heart of how R is managed and won't get implemented anytime soon. ;)

Comment: Dear @RHertel. Obviously I didn't intend to offend you. *I may still have problems in writing to so culturally-diversified population, like the one in SO*. Every command on your question begins with `system(...)` call, which often fails on memory-congested environment. And the `system(...)` call spawns a separate process, that is unaware of memory limits (maybe there is a way to circumvent this?). So any solution based on this fails in both bullet-points I put in the question. And this is exactly what I meant with my comment. **How would you put it, if you were in my shoes?**

Comment: You do not need `system()` to access content below `/proc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem and I think you can actually get around it via using `Rcpp`. Here is a possible solution (comments in the code):

```
#install ulimit package from github
#devtools::install_github("krlmlr/ulimit")

#one should delete all objects from workspace
#you have to uncomment that out yourself :)
#rm(list=ls())

library(Rcpp)

#source code for function that gets the memory used by a process
#taken from
#stackoverflow.com/questions/669438/how-to-get-memory-usage-at-run-time-in-c
src_string_1="
long mem_used_bytes(int pid) {
    long rss = 0L;
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    std::string file_path=\"/proc/\"+std::to_string(pid)+\"/statm\";
    if ( (fp = fopen(file_path.c_str(), \"r\" )) == NULL )
        return (size_t)0L;      /* Can't open? */
    if ( fscanf( fp, \"%*s%ld\", &rss ) != 1 )
    {
        fclose( fp );
        return (size_t)0L;      /* Can't read? */
    }
    fclose( fp );
    return (size_t)rss * (size_t)sysconf( _SC_PAGESIZE);
}
"

#source code for function that gets available memory
#code snippets taken from http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrlimit
src_string_2="
long mem_limit_bytes(int pid_int) {
    long res;
    struct rlimit tmp;
    pid_t pid=pid_int;
    prlimit(pid, RLIMIT_AS, NULL, &tmp);
    if (tmp.rlim_cur==-1L) {
      //there is no memory limit for the current process (should be default)
      Rcpp::Rcout<<\"No limit detected\\n\";
      struct sysinfo tmp2;
      sysinfo(&tmp2);
      res = tmp2.mem_unit * tmp2.totalram;
    } else {
      //memory limit set
      Rcpp::Rcout<<\"Limit detected\\n\";
      res=tmp.rlim_cur;
    }
    return res;
}
"

#compile functions; for convenience, we use c++11
cppFunction(src_string_1,
            plugins=c("cpp11"),
            includes=c("#include <string>",
                       "#include <sys/resource.h>",
                       "#include <unistd.h>"))
cppFunction(src_string_2,
            includes=c("#include <sys/resource.h>",
                       "#include <unistd.h>",
                       "#include <sys/sysinfo.h> "))

#memory without limit set; returns total system memory
mem_limit_bytes(Sys.getpid())/1e6
#No limit detected
#[1] 8228.246

#set limit for current R process
ulimit::memory_limit(4000)

#now the C++ function will detect the limit
mem_limit_bytes(Sys.getpid())/1e6
#Limit detected
#[1] 4194.304
```

Now try out the `mem_used_bytes` function

```
#first some garbage collection
gc()
old_mem_mb=mem_used_bytes(Sys.getpid())/1e6

#allocate a matrix with approx 800MB
NN=1e4
expected_memory_mb=NN^2*8/1e6
A=matrix(runif(NN**2),NN,NN)

#garbage collection, again
gc()

#query used memory again
new_mem_mb=mem_used_bytes(Sys.getpid())/1e6

#the following value should be close to 1
(new_mem_mb-old_mem_mb)/expected_memory_mb
```

**Edit:** Here is a somewhat simpler one-file version, reduced to the headers needed and using plain C++:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
long mem_used_bytes(int pid) {
    long rss = 0L;
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    char filepath[128];
    snprintf(filepath, 127, "/proc/%d/statm", pid);
    if ( (fp = fopen(filepath, "r" )) == NULL )
        return (size_t)0L;      /* Can't open? */
    if ( fscanf( fp, "%*s%ld", &rss ) != 1 ) {
        fclose( fp );
        return (size_t)0L;      /* Can't read? */
    }
    fclose( fp );
    return (size_t)rss * (size_t)sysconf( _SC_PAGESIZE);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
long mem_limit_bytes(int pid_int) {
    long res;
    struct rlimit tmp;
    pid_t pid=pid_int;
    prlimit(pid, RLIMIT_AS, NULL, &tmp);
    if (tmp.rlim_cur==-1L) {
        //there is no memory limit for the current process (should be default)
        Rcpp::Rcout << "No limit detected\n";
        struct sysinfo tmp2;
        sysinfo(&tmp2);
        res = tmp2.mem_unit * tmp2.totalram;
    } else {
        //memory limit set
        Rcpp::Rcout << "Limit detected\n";
        res=tmp.rlim_cur;
    }
    return res;
}

/*** R
## memory without limit set; returns total system memory
mem_limit_bytes(Sys.getpid())/1e6

## try out the `mem_used_bytes` function
## first some garbage collection
gc()
old_mem_mb <- mem_used_bytes(Sys.getpid())/1e6

## allocate a matrix with approx 800MB
NN <- 1e4
expected_memory_mb <- NN^2 * 8 / 1e6
A <- matrix(runif(NN**2),NN,NN)

##garbage collection, again
gc()

## query used memory again
new_mem_mb <- mem_used_bytes(Sys.getpid())/1e6

## the following value should be close to 1
(new_mem_mb - old_mem_mb)/expected_memory_mb

*/
```

Comment: Really good answer.  I'll edited it a little.  Shall we make it a post at the Rcpp Gallery?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks (also for the edit)! Re Rcpp Gallery: Yes, of course - just tell me what I have to do.

Comment: Have a look at [the wiki entry on contributing](https://github.com/RcppCore/rcpp-gallery/wiki/Contributing-to-the-Rcpp-Gallery) -- and then maybe send a pull request?   Using Rcpp to get to system level C calls is clearly underappreciated and underdocumented. We should write this page.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Ok, will do. Might take some time, though, as I will be traveling over the next two weeks. But I'll work it out somehow.